# Creating a realm record with a linked property

Tags: realm

I am just starting with realm and I have two objects that I think I have created properly.  A ColourCategory can have many objects of type PaletteColour

```
class PaletteColour: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var category: ColorCategory?
}

class ColourCategory: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let paletteColours = List<PaletteColour>()
}
```

I have created many categories just by creating them with the name.
Now, I want to add colours and one of the properties of the PaletteColour is that it must have a link to the Category Object by name.

I am stuck on how to create a PaletteColour object using one of my category names.

I start with this

```
let realm = try! Realm()
newColour = PaletteColour()
newColour.name = "Red"
// This is where I am stuck
// How do I add a category property that has a name of "Test Category" and linked to the ColourCategory object
newColour.category = ????????????
realm.write {
  realm.add(newColour)
}
```

I am sure that this is pretty straight forward so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create `ColourCategory` instance and assign to `category` property to link colour and category objects.

```
// Create category object named "Test Category"
let category = ColourCategory()
category.name = "Test Category"
// then, assign to `category` propety
newColour.category = category;

realm.write {
    realm.add(newColour)
}
```

You can also use "backlink" mechanism for `palleteColours` property. If you use "backlink", you do not need to manage the inverse relationship for `paletteColours`.

```
class ColourCategory: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    var paletteColours: [PaletteColour] {
        return linkingObjects(PaletteColour.self, forProperty: "category")
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work  I get two PaletteColour entries but no associated ColorCategory. see [Image](http://www.screencast.com/t/P9zhLGpd)

Comment: @StewartLynch How do you check that? If you check the date with the debugger, the debugger doesn't show Realm objects correctly because Realm objects loaded lazily.

Comment: I just opened the database in Realm Browser so I am not sure what you are asking.  That image in my last comment was a snapshot of the two tables in Realm Browser.
I am a little frustrated.  I am use to working with relational databases so I am tying to get my head around this.  I really wish that there was a working example in Swift showing  how to Add, Modify and delete records in a two table, relational type database.  The examples on the realm site show dog and person, but no example code that I can find that shows how to work with querying, updating or modifying records.

Comment: That code should work. Could you please make sure to assign category object to the colour's category property?

Comment: When I do that, I get a new "Test Category" entry added to the ColorCategory table so it does not link to the one that was already there.

Comment: You can also in the same way if you'd like to link the fetched objects. Assign the category object that you fetched to colour's category property, then add the colour object to Realm.